# Fullcalendar Issue: Time slot selected incorrectly in day view

Tags: fullcalendar

In day view when you click on a time slot, it selects a later time slot. Works fine on very early hours (upto 3 am or so) and then the time slot selected moves to 30 to 90 minutes later than what is actually clicked on.

The demo on http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ works fine so it's something in my custom css that may be the problem.

I am using Firefox 12.0 and FullCalendar 1.5.3 on the client side and the server side is WAMP and CodeIgniter (but all server side code works fine).

These are the previous reports I found, but no clear resolution:
code dot google dot com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=631
code dot google dot com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1216

It won't be possible to post my code since it's part of a large app. So without that, any ideas where I should look?

Comment: Have exactly the same issue - let me know if you figured how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I have just had the same problem.

It was caused by two rules in my custom css. The first was a general "line-height" setting in my reset.css (removing this made the biggest difference). The other was a padding rule applied to:

```
#calendar table {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Once I removed both these rules, the time slots could be selected accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the answer from Ryan Nel:

I had the same situation where the font-family was overriden by my "theme" stylesheet forcing the calendar slot select to be off on hours late on the day.

I added the following line to my theme CSS to enforce line height on the calendar:

```
.fc-agenda-slots {
    line-height: 1em !important;
}
```

It worked for me, but there might be other things like padding you want to enforce as well. Just add the rules within the same brackets.